# TelemetryClient.Flush not being called with Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, autofac, azure-application-insights

I have the following configuration in my .NET Framework 4.7.2 console app:

```
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

containerBuilder.Register(CreateTelemetryClient).As<TelemetryClient>().OnRelease(HandleTelemetryClientDisposal);
```

```
private static void HandleTelemetryClientDisposal(TelemetryClient client)
        {
            client.Flush();
        }

private static TelemetryClient CreateTelemetryClient(IComponentContext context)
        {
            var instrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"];
            var configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
            configuration.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey;
            var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(configuration);
            telemetryClient.Context.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey;
            var telemetryInitializer = context.Resolve<ITelemetryInitializer>();
            configuration.TelemetryInitializers.Add(telemetryInitializer);

            return telemetryClient;
        }
```

This correctly configures the telemetry client for Application Insights logging. However, the `OnRelease(HandleTelemetryClientDisposal)` is never called and therefore neither is `client.Flush()` which I believe is why my logs aren't appearing in App Insights.

Why isn't this being called - have I configured this incorrectly?

Edit to show more code:

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var jobHostConfig = new JobHostConfiguration();
            IocConfig.Configure(jobHostConfig );
        }
    }
```

```
 public static void Configure(JobHostConfiguration jobHostConfiguratio)
        {
            var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

            RegisterDependencies(containerBuilder);

            jobHostConfiguration.JobActivator = new AutofacActivator(containerBuilder.Build());
        }
```

```
private static void RegisterDependencies(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder) 
{ 

   containerBuilder.Register(CreateTelemetryClient).As<TelemetryClient>().OnRelease(HandleTelemetryClientDisposal);
}
```

Comment: Need more information: What's consuming the telemetry client? Since OnRelease happens when the container (or lifetime scope) is disposed, where's the code showing when the container is built, when the lifetime scope starts, and when those things get disposed?

Comment: Hi thanks @TravisIllig I have added some more code - I am not sure if lifetime scope has been configured - I am new to Autofac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what's going on since I don't know what `JobHostConfiguration`, `JobActivator`, or `AutofacActivator` are, however, I do know Autofac. Some quick Googling makes me think this has something to do with Hangfire, so if this doesn't answer your question... it might be good to mention Hangfire in the question and/or tag it `hangfire` because it's going to have to do with Hangfire application lifecycle things.

**OnRelease happens when the lifetime scope is disposed.** [We have some docs](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/events.html#onrelease) on it, but that's the gist - it's like adding `IDisposable` to a class that isn't disposable. [There's a lot of doc explaining how disposal relates to containers and scopes.](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html)

From a practical standpoint, what it means is if nothing calls `Dispose` on the container or lifetime scope, you won't get `OnRelease` called.

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register(CreateTelemetryClient)
  .As<TelemetryClient>()
  .OnRelease(HandleTelemetryClientDisposal);
var container = builder.Build();
using(var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
  var client = scope.Resolve<TelemetryClient>();

  // When this closing brace is hit, the lifetime scope
  // will be disposed, and the OnRelease will be called.
}
```

You'll notice I showed the example using a lifetime scope. If you had resolved from the container directly, you'd have to dispose of the container... and then you can't use the container anymore.

*This is where my lack of knowledge of Hangfire comes in.* I don't know *when* the `TelemetryClient` is being resolved, I don't know what's using it, I don't know if it's coming from the *container* or from a *lifetime scope*, and I don't know when the container/scope is being disposed. That's something you're going to have to figure out, but it looks like [the Hangfire.Autofac README covers some of the examples](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire.Autofac).

The symptom you describe, though, where `OnRelease` is never called so `Flush` is never called... indicates that things aren't being disposed of properly, so that's where you'd need to start looking. This is, of course, assuming that something is resolving it in the first place - if nothing resolves it, then there's nothing to dispose, and of course the `OnRelease` won't be called. Again, there's nothing in your code showing anything *consuming* the `TelemetryClient`, so as a standalone example... no, you'd never see `OnRelease` called because there's nothing in your code shown here that takes a dependency on a `TelemetryClient`. The client won't be resolved simply by virtue of registering it. Something has to consume it.

Comment: Thanks so much for that helpful response @TravisIllig . I have one more question - where would you normally put that using block? Is that also in the configuration?